# Detect network issues with JS

Tags: javascript, internet-connection

trying to implement a tricky internet connection detector with JS and got a blocker. The idea is that I use ping/pong method to see that I am online or not. It works fine for Online/Offline mode, but I need to extend this "a little bit".

Offline can be because of 2 things:

1. WiFi is OFF or Internet Cable is unplugged;
2. WiFi is ON or Inter Cable is plugged, although I don't have internet connection because of some reasons.

So, basically the second point it is the tricky moment.

Here is the code which I have at the moment to detect Online/Offline mode:

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  let img = document.createElement("img");
  currentRequestsCount += 1;

  img.onerror = () => {
    currentRequestsCount = currentRequestsCount > 0 ? currentRequestsCount - 1 : 0;
    status = 'offline';
  };

  img.onload = () => {
    currentRequestsCount = currentRequestsCount > 0 ? currentRequestsCount - 1 : 0;
    status = 'online';
  };

  img.src = "https://www.google.com/favicon.ico?_" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000));

  setTimeout(() => {
    img = null;
  });
}, 3000);
```

Any help and advices here are WELCOME!

Comment: I suggest a different approach - assume that the connection is on and just catch and handle any call that fails. There are tons of tutorials that show how such **offline** apps should be written.

Comment: There is an experimental [Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API)

Comment: Thanks guys, but that what you suggest are not related to my case. I already know how to handle offline/online mode. I am looking how to handle a new status: 'Internet Connection with Issues"

Comment: If your app has already determined that the WiFi is ON (cable is plugged) but you want to test whether the Gateway and/or DNS are setup properly - you can simply try to fetch `index.html` from your website - once by hostname and once by IP address. If both fail - then you have "Internet Connection with issues"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine

Comment: @Bergi this doesn't work correctly, you can try to break your internet connection and write in console: navigator.online, will see that it always shows true

Comment: @ExariConstantin What do you mean by "break your internet connection"? If you pull the cable or turn off the wifi at your computer, it will work. If the connection is lost elsewhere, it'll take some time until the OS figures out it cannot reach any target. If what you actually want is to check whether a *specific* target becomes inaccessible, you have no way other than continuous polling.

Comment: @Bergi I have tried in last version of Chrome to turn OFF the WiFi, after that i've tried tried to run navigator.online in the Chrome console, it was always show true, instead of showing false.

Comment: @ExariConstantin Works for me. Maybe you [have some second network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39660113/1048572) still connected to something?

Comment: Regardless, your code should work. What exactly is the problem you're having with it?

Comment: @Bergi above code works fine when I want to detect online/offline. With that question I am looking to a new status: 'issues'. Will try to explain one more time, what does it mean for me 'issues' status. For example your WiFi is connected or Cable is plugged in, but because of some network problems, you don't have internet connection. That's what I what to handle. I hope that make sense?